# Changing landing page for react website , localhost

Tags: html, reactjs, routes

I deployed one website on localhost, with `npm build` / `react`, and I would like to select another landing page.

However I'm a newbie working with React and I don't know where to find the routes for the pages. I have the following codes in the `public/Index.html`, `public/manifest.json`, and `package.json` from root folder.
I tried modifying the `homepage`  in `package.json` to another folder/.ts/.tsx files but without any success.

Any idea in how to find the routes to other pages and how to set the landing page to them for localhost server ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't touch the public folder for routes, and assuming you want to link to another page like you want to go from / to /about then you need to do this:
this will be your home page - app.tsx

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

    function App() {
       return (
          <BrowserRouter>
             <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
             </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

this will be your about file, about.tsx

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function About() {
  return (
     <div>
       <nav>
        <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
       </nav>
    </div>
 );
}
```

To understand more about routes please check the documentation below
[React router V6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)